# How to access elements of a std::vector<cv::Mat> and put them in separate matrices cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, stdvector, opencv-mat

I have a `const std::vector<cv::Mat>` containing 3 matrices (3 images), and in order to use each image further in my program I need to save them in separate matrices `cv::Mat`.
I know that I need to iterate over vector elements, since this vector is a list of matrices but somehow I can't manage it. At the end, I also need to push 3 matrices back to a vector.
I would appreciate if someone could help me out with this. I am still learning it.

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> imagesRGB;
cv::Mat imgR, imgG, imgB;

for(size_t i=0; i<imagesRGB.size(); i++)
{
   imagesRGB[i].copyTo(imgR);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, note that `imagesRGB` is uninitialized, and its size is `0`. The `for` loop is not evaluated. Additionally, the `copyTo` method copies matrix data into another matrix (like a *paste* function), it is not used to store a `cv::Mat` into a `std::vector`.

Your description is not clear enough, however here's an example of what I think you might be needing. If you want to split an `RGB` (3 channels) image into three individual mats, you can do it using the `cv::split` function. If you want to merge 3 individual channels into an `RGB` mat, you can do that via the `cv::merge` function. Let's see the example using [this](https://www.cosy.sbg.ac.at/%7Epmeerw/Watermarking/lena.html) test image:

```
//Read input image:
cv::Mat inputImage = cv::imread( "D://opencvImages//lena512.png" );

//Split the BGR image into its channels:
cv::Mat splitImage[3];
cv::split(inputImage, splitImage);

//show images:
cv::imshow("B", splitImage[0]);
cv::imshow("G", splitImage[1]);
cv::imshow("R", splitImage[2]);
```

Note that I'm already storing the channels in an `array`. However, if you want to store the individual mats into a `std::vector`, you can use the `push_back` method:

```
//store the three channels into a vector:
std::vector<cv::Mat> matVector;

for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){
    //get current channel:
    cv::Mat currentChannel = splitImage[i];
    //store into vector
    matVector.push_back(currentChannel);
}

//merge the three channels back into an image:
cv::Mat mergedImage;
cv::merge(matVector, mergedImage);

//show final image:
cv::imshow("Merged Image", mergedImage);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

This is the result:

[image]